# How do I mock IConfiguration with Moq?

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core-mvc, moq, xunit

How do I mock code like this in my unit test. I'm using xUnit and Moq in asp.net core 5. I'm new to xUnit and Moq.

```
var url = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetSection("SmsApi").Value;
```

The configuration object is already injected into the constructor.

This is what I currently have in my unit test class

```
public class UtilityTests
{
    private readonly Utility sut;

    public UtilityTests()
    {
        var mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
        var mockConfigSection = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
        //mockConfigSection.Setup(x => x.Path).Returns("AppSettings");
        mockConfigSection.Setup(x => x.Key).Returns("SmsApi");
        mockConfigSection.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns("http://example.com");
        
        mockConfig.Setup(x => x.GetSection("AppSettings")).Returns(mockConfigSection.Object);
        
        sut = new Utility(mockConfig.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void SendSmsShdReturnTrue()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        
        var result = sut.SendSms(fixture.Create<string>(), fixture.Create<string>());
        result.Should().BeTrue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it appSettings.json or web.config ? Sample file would be helpful.

Comment: It's .net core so app settings.json

Comment: @plasteezy Did any of the suggested solution work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative approach tp introduce a class to represent section of the configuration, then use `IOptions` interface to inject it to the constructor.

Your tests then become simple to configure without mocking, just create an instance and pass it to the constructor.

Something like below:

```
class SmsApiSettings
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Register during startup

```
services.Configure<SmsApiSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SmsApi"));
```

Constructor

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
    private readonly SmsApiSettings _smsApiSettings;

    public ClassUnderTest(IOptions<> smsOptions)
    {
        _smsApiSettings = smsOptions.Value;
    }
}
```

Tests

```
var settings = new SmsApiSettings { Url = "http://dummy.com" };
var options = Options.Create(settings);

var sut = new ClassUnderTest(options);
```

Enjoy happy life without mocks ;)

Comment: I like this method, its a more elegant way to handle it. Thanks @Fabio

Comment: I feel like a lot more context would not go amiss. (Around the code snippets.)

Answer (score 13):

The truth is that the `IConfiguration` should not be mocked. Instead it should be [built](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder).

### via dictionary

#### Data

```cs
var configForSmsApi = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"AppSettings:SmsApi", "http://example.com"},
};
```

#### Usage

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(configForSmsApi)
    .Build();
```

### via json file

#### Data

```json
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "SmsApi": "http://example.com"
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("smsapi.json", optional: false)
    .Build();
```

Comment: Why should `IConfiguration` not be mocked?

Comment: @Yíu It can be mocked, but it is easier to build one via a Dictionary. Otherwise you have to mock several `GetSection` with different parameters (see the OP's example).

Comment: @Yíu You might also use extension methods of IConfiguration. You cannot mock those.